# Using cache-control: only-if-cached

Tags: javascript, browser, http-headers, fetch

I would like to make a request from browser JS code that only succeeds if there is a response in the cache, and otherwise errors.

The `Cache-Control: only-if-cached` header discussed [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) sounds like just what I need:

> The client indicates that an already-cached response should be returned. If a cache has a stored response, even a stale one, it will be returned. If no cached response is available, a 504 Gateway Timeout response will be returned.

But in practice I just can't get that to work. If I run this code in the console on any page on the web:

```js
fetch("/" + Math.floor(Math.random() * Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).toString(), {
  headers: {
    "Cache-Control": "only-if-cached",
  },
}).then((res) => {
  console.log('Fetch', res.status);
});
```

I just get a plain old 404 and I can see that an HTTP request was made to the server. Why doesn't this result in a 504? I observe the same behavior in both Chrome and Firefox.

I also found a top-level option in the fetch API that sounds like it's supposed to do the same thing. As discussed on [MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache) fetch supports a `cache` property in its request options, which also supports `only-if-cached` as a value. It states there:

> only-if-cached — The browser looks for a matching request in its HTTP cache.
> If there is a match, fresh or stale, it will be returned from the cache.
> If there is no match, the browser will respond with a 504 Gateway timeout status.

I gave that a shot and it seems to work... but not as described. Rather than returning a 504 status, it throws a `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource` when I try this code:

```js
fetch("/" + Math.floor(Math.random() * Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).toString(), {
  cache: 'only-if-cached',
  mode: 'same-origin',
}).then((res) => {
  console.log('Fetch', res.status);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

And the network tools in Firefox show `NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED` for the request. So, getting warmer, but where's this 504 response the documentation talks about? Unfortunately the error thrown in code in that case doesn't look specific enough for me to distinguish it from other sorts of errors.

I've tried throwing the code in `<script>` tags and running it on a local server, and with all extensions disabled, but am getting the same behavior. The documentation seems clear and direct yet the described behavior eludes me. I am mainly using Firefox 12.1.0 64-bit Windows.

Comment: The way the [`fetch` specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#requests) is written, it appears that when you don't specify the `cache` parameter the behavior is `default`, which won't implement the `only-if-cached` behavior. It just sees that it's not in the cache and sends out a regular network request. I agree that that's counterintuitive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @KevinChristopherHenry . I noticed the spec you linked to doesn't appear to say anything about a `504` response (which does seem like an odd way to report a cache miss). I wonder if MDN is outdated or just incorrect on this.

Comment: That's discussed in [RFC 9111](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-only-if-cached), the HTTP caching spec. These are two different specifications. Fetch defines a programming API. HTTP defines a communication protocol for independent network nodes (including generic proxy caches).